# Shared object in R

Tags: r, fortran, shared-objects

I want to run a FORTRAN subroutine from R. I read that, I need a shared object (.so file) to run the subroutine.
For creating the shared object I successfully compiled the FORTRAN subroutine.
But when creating shared object it gave the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: temain.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be 
used when making a shared object; 
recompile with -fPIC
temain.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the command given was `gfortran -shared -o temain.so *.o`

What do I do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `-fPIC` as the error message says.

See the Writing R Extensions manual and use `R CMD COMPILE myfile.f`.

Comment: That solved it (with a lot of warnings). It gave error previously because I did not delete the .o file created before.

Comment: You _obviously_ have to remove and rebuild that. That was the whole point: object code without relocation info.